# What does Fatal Exception: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException setSpan (14 ... 14) ends beyond length 0 actaully mean in natural language?

Tags: android, android-edittext

Well, I recently encounter an exception like this when I try to set text to and EditText - actually, a tester that used an automation testing tool cause the exception but it's not relevant.

Fatal Exception: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
setSpan (14 ... 14) ends beyond length 0
android.widget.EditText.setSelection (EditText.java:128)

I just wanna know how to interpret the exception above to natural language? Does the EditText want to say "You moron developer want me to set my cursor at index 14 while there is no text inside me"